# Preg_replace return $1 insted of real content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having this a function inside a `preg_replace()`.

I am using it like this:

```
$pattern[] = "/\[test\](.*?)\[\/test\]/is";
$replace[] = $this->test('$1');

$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

Then the function `test()` prints out the value which is sent to it.
But the value is always just `$1`, while it should be the content from `[test]...[/test]`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`test()` will never receive the value of `$1`, it will always get the literal string `"$1"`. When you do `$this->test()`, you call the `test()` function, and it receives what you put in the parenthesis as arguments.

By the time `test()` executes, the regular expression has yet to be evaluated. You would have to do:

```
$pattern = "/\[test\](.*?)\[\/test\]/is";
$content = $this->test( preg_replace( $pattern, '$1', $content));
```

This would cause `test()` to receive the value of `$1`. Otherwise, you'd need `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$pattern[] = "/\[test\](.*?)\[\/test\]/is";
$content = preg_replace($pattern, function( $match) { 
    return $this->test( $match[1]); 
}, $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the matches being replaced by the return value of the `$this->test` method with the corresponding matched string of the first sub-pattern, you need to use `preg_replace_callback` and a wrapper function instead:

```
$pattern = "/\[test\](.*?)\[\/test\]/is";
$replace = function($match) use ($this) { return $this->test($match[1]); };
$content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

Answer (score -2):

Single quotes means literal string.

so `'$1'` will return `$1`

while `"$1"` will interpret the regex captured value stored in `$1` to its value

Comment: I guess using single quotes is intended. It should be replaced by the value of the first capture group of the expression. Variables cannot start with numbers anyway afaik.

Comment: yes, the first capture group, I suppose 'variable' was the wrong word to use here

Comment: Oh, no, in that case it does not matter whether you use single or double quotes.